# MySQL Counting occurrences of an ID

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the following query which returns event details and a rank based on the number of votes.

```
SELECT e.guid, e.name, e.desc, e.location, e.votes,
       @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM event e, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

This gives me the required output. However because I want to store more information about who has voted (to determine if a user can vote - as 1 vote per person is allowed). I created a new table called **event_votes** which looks like:

```
event_vote_id | event_guid | user_guid
       1           abc1         def6
       2           ghi4         def6
       3           abc1         lmn2
```

How can I get the first query to work again replacing e.votes (a field which increments) with the number of occurrences of event_guid in **event_votes**

*Expected Result*

guid: abc1

name: testevent

desc: example

location: London

votes: 2

rank: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test it, but hopefully, it works.

```
SELECT e.guid, e.name, e.desc, e.location, 
    (SELECT COUNT(ev.id) FROM event_votes ev WHERE ev.event_guid = e.guid) AS votes,
           @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM event e, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
    ORDER BY votes DESC
```

Comment: it's better to do a real left join

Comment: @DanielE. It depends on needs. The subquery is better than left join if you have only one select, at least I think like that :) but of course, we can also use real left join.

Comment: However, the rank is broken, if I have an event with 1 vote and the rest have none, it is ranked 2nd. Any ideas?

Comment: @H1ggsy The fastest and dirty way is returning null instead of 0. 

```
SELECT e.guid, e.name, e.desc, e.location, 
    (SELECT IF(COUNT(ev.id) > 0, COUNT(ev.id), NULL) FROM event_votes ev WHERE ev.event_guid = e.guid) AS votes,
           @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM event e, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
    ORDER BY votes DESC
```